# PosgreSQL Syntax conversion to snowflake - Issue with Group by Clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to covert the below syntax in PostgreSQL sql to snowflake. Post conversion to snowflake it throws me the error to add snapshot in groupby clause

**PostgreSQL Query**

```
select row_number()
    over (
      order by snapshot_date )                                           AS month_no,
  *
from (
  SELECT
       date_trunc('month', snapshot_date) :: date                                AS month_date,
    MIN(snapshot_date)                                                        AS month_start,
    MAX(snapshot_date)                                                        AS month_end,
    MAX(snapshot_date)                                                        as snapshot_date,
    (date_trunc('month', snapshot_date) + INTERVAL '1 month - 1 day') :: DATE as eow,
    lag(MAX(snapshot_date), 1)
    over (
      order by
        date_trunc('month', snapshot_date) :: date   ) as prev_month_end
  FROM sample.sample
  WHERE snapshot_date >= ('2020-10-10')
   and snapshot_date < date_trunc('week', current_date)
   GROUP BY date_trunc('month', snapshot_date),
    EXTRACT(month FROM snapshot_date)
  ORDER BY 3 DESC
)a where month_end>('2020-10-10');
```

The above query returns 3 records as

[image]

I'm using below snowflake query. while executing it asks for the snapshot date to be added, and if I add it does the group by on snapshot date and returns 31 records.
So in short I don't want to group by on snapshot date as it should only be group by on month start and month number.

**Snowflake Query**

```
select row_number()
    over (
      order by snapshot_date )                                           AS month_no,
  *
from (
  SELECT
    
    date_trunc('month', snapshot_date :: date)                                AS month_date,
    MIN(snapshot_date)                                                        AS month_start,
    MAX(snapshot_date)                                                        AS month_end,
    MAX(snapshot_date)                                                        as snapshot_date,
    last_day(snapshot_date) as eow,
    lag(MAX(snapshot_date), 1)
    over (
      order by
        date_trunc('month', snapshot_date :: date)   ) as prev_month_end
  FROM fincor.fx_rate
  WHERE snapshot_date >= ('2020-10-10')
   and snapshot_date < date_trunc('week', current_date)
 
  GROUP BY date_trunc('month', snapshot_date),
    EXTRACT(month FROM snapshot_date)
  ORDER BY 3 DESC
)a where month_end>('2020-10-10');
```

**ERROR**

[image]

Comment: Try renaming the `MAX(snapshot_date)` output to something other than snapshot_date.  I think it might be confused that you are referencing multiple columns with the same name in your query.  And why are you grouping by the same thing twice?  Lastly, I'm surprised that it's not complaining about the `ORDER BY` statement inside the sub-query.

Comment: I updated the query but still having same issue. If you can share the your version of updated query that will be really helpful.

Comment: @MikeWalton, Could you please share your version of updated query that you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

The error you get, can be fixed by adding "date conversion":

```
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', snapshot_date :: date )
```

When you add "group by", "last_day(snapshot_date) as eow" also causes an error, as SNAPSHOT_DATE is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause. The final version of the SQL statement should be like this:

```
select  row_number()
    over (
      order by snapshot_date ) AS month_no, 
  *
from (
  SELECT
    date_trunc('month', snapshot_date :: date)                                AS month_date,
    MIN(snapshot_date)                                                        AS month_start,
    MAX(snapshot_date)                                                        AS month_end,
    MAX(snapshot_date)                                                        as snapshot_date,
    last_day(MAX(snapshot_date)) as eow,
    lag(MAX(snapshot_date), 1)
    over (
      order by
        date_trunc('month', snapshot_date :: date)   ) as prev_month_end 
  FROM fincor.fx_rate
  WHERE snapshot_date >= ('2020-10-10')
   and snapshot_date < date_trunc('week', current_date)
  GROUP BY date_trunc('month', snapshot_date :: date )
   , EXTRACT(month FROM snapshot_date)
  ORDER BY 3 DESC
) a where month_end > ('2020-10-10');
```